# General term of Taylor Series of $\sin x$ centered at $\pi/4$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, power-series, taylor-expansion

What is the general term for a Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ centered at $\pi/4$?

It should be $(-1)^{[??]} \times \sqrt{2}/2 \times \frac{(x-\pi/4)^n}{n!}$

What power is $(-1)$ supposed to be raised to?

Answer (score 9):

Write $f(x)=\sin x$. Then your Taylor series at $\pi/4$ is
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{f^{(n)}(\pi/4)}{n!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^n
$$

Compute the first derivatives at $\pi/4$ and see the pattern. This is periodic. You can guess the sign.

**Edit:** So the sequence $f^{(n)}(\pi/4)$ is, from $n=0$:
$$
+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, +\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\ldots
$$
This can be given by:
$$
f^{(n)}(\pi/4)=(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.
$$

Comment: But the pattern isn't 1,-1,1,-1. It's actually 1,1,-1,-1 given that sin(pi/4) and cos(pi/4) both are positive.

Comment: @Aleksandr I just gave an example. For $a_0=1, a_1=1, a_2=-1, a_3=-1$, we can take $a_n=(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$, for instance.

Comment: Plugging test values for n: (-1)^[n/2]...

n = 0 = -1
n = 1 = 1/sq.rt(-1)
n = 2 = -1
n = 3 = -1 * 1/sq.rt(-1)

I understand how to complete Taylor Series for more common patterns, but I am struggling with a way to express the 1,1,-1,-1 pattern of sin(x) centered about pi/4.

Comment: @Aleksandr For $n=0$, we get $(-1)^0=1$. For $n=1$, $\lfloor 1/2\rfloor =0$, so $1$ again. For $n=2$, $\lfloor 2/2\rfloor =1$, so we get $-1$. And for $n=3$, $\lfloor 3/2\rfloor =1$, hence we obtain $-1$. It works...

Comment: @Aleksandr Just in case: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the [floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). That is the largest integer not greater than $x$. the values of $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ are, strating from $n=0$: $0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,\ldots$. When you put this as an exponent of $-1$, you do recover $1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,\ldots$.

Comment: The floor function works great! I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the exponent $\frac{n(n+1)}2$. So $-1$ raised to the power $\frac{n(n+1)}2$ will produce the sequence desired.

Comment: I just realized that this is *not* correct. The correct exponent would be $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. The signs are ++--++--...

Comment: @robjohn If you are starting an $n=0$ (which you are) then you need to translate a little more.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re saying. $(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}2}$ gives the proper sign: $0\to1,1\to1,2\to-1,3\to-1,\dots$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the result

$$ f^{(n)}(x)= \sin\left( x+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right) \implies f^{(n)}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)= \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right) $$

to construct the Taylor series at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$. It is not hard to prove the above result. Just use the identity

$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{2i}\left( e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right). $$

Comment: Could you point me towards a more explicit derivation?

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ will give you even, odd, odd, even, even, ...
$\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}+n$ will give you even, even, odd, odd,
giving us the desired $+,+,-,-$

Comment: You should make clear that this is the exponent of $-1$. See [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330890/general-term-of-taylor-series-of-sin-x-centered-at-pi-4/435238?noredirect=1#comment931913_435238).